# Populate Django form from 3rd party POST with different field names

Tags: django, post, django-forms

My Django app will be handling post data from a 3rd party payment processor.  I would like to use a Django form to sanitize and deal with this data, but the POST variables have names that are not valid names for Django form fields.  How can I re-map these to my form?

So, I have a form:

```
class PayResponseForm(forms.Form):
    status = forms.Charfield()
    message = forms.CharField()
    avs_code = forms.CharField(max_length=1)
```

And the post I get from the 3rd part site looks like:

```
request.POST['FinalStatus']
request.POST['MErrMsg']
request.POST['avs-code']
```

How do I map these post variable to my form fields?  Will it cause problems if, in my view, I just do something like `request.POST['status'] = request.POST['FinalStatus']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own dict for form init:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if need_to_convert_post(request):
        post = {
            'field1': None,
            'field2': None,
            'field3': None,
        }
        post['field1'] = request.POST.get('SomeOtherField1', None)
    else:
        post = request.POST
    form = Form1(post)
else:
    form = Form1()
```

and detect when you need to change post:

```
def need_to_convert_post(request):
    if 'uniqueCheckField' in request.POST:
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: Thanks for the well thought out example.  Moral of the story: feed that form a dict.

Answer (score 1):

For tidyness, you could use `request.POST['status'] = request.POST.pop('FinalStatus')`, otherwise it's perfectly fine to use your approach.